# How to config default port of Node Exporter

Tags: port, system, default, monitor, prometheus-node-exporter

I deploy Node Exporter for monitor my system, but some app in my server used port 9100 , and Node Export Services cannot start.?
How to change another port for Node_Exporter

Thank for reading, this is my fist post

I try on RHEL 8

```
Jul 24 14:43:11 xxxxxxx node_exporter[16516]: time="2019-0724T14:43:11+07:00" level=info msg="Build context (go=go1.12.5, user=root@b50852a1acba,date=20190604-16:41:18)" source="node_exporter.go:157"
Jul 24 14:43:11 xxxxxxx node_exporter[16516]: time="2019-07-24T14:43:11+07:00" level=info msg="Enabled collectors:" source="node_exporter.go:97"
Jul 24 14:43:11 xxxxxxx node_exporter[16516]: time="2019-07-24T14:43:11+07:00" level=info msg=" - arp" source="node_exporter.go:104"
Jul 24 14:43:11 xxxxxxx node_exporter[16516]: time="2019-07-24T14:43:11+07:00" level=info msg=" - bcache" source="node_exporter.go:104"
Jul 24 14:43:11 xxxxxxx node_exporter[16516]: time="2019-07-24T14:43:11+07:00" level=info msg=" - bonding" source="node_exporter.go:104"
Jul 24 14:43:11 xxxxxxx node_exporter[16516]: time="2019-07-24T14:43:11+07:00" level=info msg=" - conntrack" source="node_exporter.go:104"
Jul 24 14:43:11 xxxxxxx node_exporter[16516]: time="2019-07-24T14:43:11+07:00" level=info msg=" - cpu" source="node_exporter.go:104"
Jul 24 14:43:11 xxxxxxx systemd[1]: node_exporter.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 24 14:43:11 xxxxxxx systemd[1]: Unit node_exporter.service entered failed state.
Jul 24 14:43:11 xxxxxxx systemd[1]: node_exporter.service failed.
```

`

Answer (score 21):

I found the answer.
Just add `--web.listen-address=:9500` behind `ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/node_exporter` in the config file
It looklike

```
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/node_exporter --web.listen-address=:[custum port]
```